# 'IAsyncOperation<>' Xamarin Forms

Tags: windows, xamarin.forms, uwp, sdk

When using the exact same code in a UWP App an Xamarin Forms app, I get the following error on the Xamarin.Forms program but not on the UWP program.

> Error CS0012  The type 'IAsyncOperation<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.

Here is my code.

```
 public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

        Task task = CopyAssetsDatabase();
    }

    private async Task CopyAssetsDatabase()
    {

        StorageFile file;

        var root = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
        var dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "ExpressEMR.db");

        try
        {
            file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ExpressEMR.db");
        }
        catch
        {
            StorageFile Importedfile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/ExpressEMR.db"));
            file = await Importedfile.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> 'IAsyncOperation<>' Xamarin Forms

The problem is that you have missed `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime` assembly, you could add it manually. right click the `Dependencies` Add reference-> Browse -> find it from this path (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`).

**Update**

> That assembly should be added automatically to a Xamarin Forms app, correct? I mean I have never had to add it manually before.

Sure, but in early version, we need add the reference manually. And I checked your thread again, I found you used `StorageFile` in forms app class. However, StorageFile is specific class for uwp platform please avoid use it in forms, if you want to file access, you could [dependency service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to access file for each platform.

Comment: Nico, That assembly should be added automatically to a Xamarin Forms app, correct?  I mean I have never had to add it manually before.

Comment: Comes up as 'already referenced' (no surprise)