# CS4036 for StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I am writing a UWP app (Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019). I want to display the drives in this app.
In order to do this, I created another smaller UWP app in order to only display the drives, then tried to put the code in the bigger UWP app. In both apps I enabled the settings in the manifest file.

The small UWP app works:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;


namespace App1
{
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        const string FREE_SPACE = "System.FreeSpace";
        const string TOTAL_SPACE = "System.Capacity";
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach(DriveInfo d in drives)
        {
            try
            {
                StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(d.RootDirectory.FullName);
                var props = await folder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new string[] { FREE_SPACE, TOTAL_SPACE });
                Debug.WriteLine("free space is:" + (UInt64)props[FREE_SPACE]);
                Debug.WriteLine("capacity is: " + (UInt64)props[TOTAL_SPACE]);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The code in the big UWP app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Windows.Storage;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private static async Task<IEnumerable<Drives>> DrivesAsync()
        {
            List<Drive> drivesList= new List<Drive>();
            const string FREE_SPACE = "System.FreeSpace";
            const string TOTAL_SPACE = "System.Capacity";
            DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

            foreach (DriveInfo d in drives)
            {
                try
                {
                    StorageFolder storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(d.RootDirectory.FullName);
                    var properties = await storageFolder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new string[] { FREE_SPACE, TOTAL_SPACE }); 
                    drivesList.Add(new Drive
                    {
                           freeSpace = (UInt64)properties[FREE_SPACE],
                           totalSpace = (UInt64)properties[TOTAL_SPACE]
                    });
            
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }

            return drivesList;
        }

        public static async Task<IEnumerable<Drive>> GetDrivesAsync()
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask;
            return await DrivesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in the bigger app at the lines

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(d.RootDirectory.FullName);
var properties = await storageFolder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new string[] { FREE_SPACE, TOTAL_SPACE });
```

I have the following error:

***CS4036   'IAsyncOperation' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncOperation' could be found (are you missing a using directive for 'System'?)***

As it can be seen, there is **using System;** at the top of the files.

Why the code in the bigger app doesn't work? How can I get rid of the error?

Comment: Do you have a reference to `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`?

Comment: Please try to place cursor over the error link, then click show potential fixes.

Comment: @StephenCleary No. How can I reference it and how is it useful?

Comment: @tp123 Please check this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62381819/7254781) and refer it manually.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who might use Xamarin & UWP. If it is not working with
using System;
check if you put in a Dependency-Logic.
StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync and other async Methods only work in the UWP-Part! You have to use a Dependency-Service.